# Autoscaling IaaS VMs in ARM mode from a template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I've created an template-based deployment that over-provisions a number of Linux VMs. I'd like to autoscale them as per classic instances, where Azure will turn on/turn off instances according to CPU load.

Is this possible with ARM mode? And if not, is there a suggested alternative method? The only examples I can find are around using Application Insights and PaaS functionality. I've got a Python app running in Docker on Ubuntu hosts.

Answer (score 1):

For IaaS, you must use virtual machine scale sets to use autoscale, else you need to stick with PaaS (web apps).

Answer (score 0):

For this you would first need to create an availability group for the VMs. The resource decleration in the ARM template looks something like this:

```
{
 "type": "Microsoft.Compute/availabilitySets",
  "name": "[variables('availabilitySetName')]",
  "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
  "location": "[parameters('location')]",
  "properties": {
       "platformFaultDomainCount": "2"
   }
}
```

Then for the virtual machine resource the decliration in the ARM Template would look something like this:

```
    {
            "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
            "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
            "name": "[concat(variables('vmName'), '0')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', parameters('newStorageAccountName'))]",
                "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/', variables('nicName'), '0')]",
                "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/availabilitySets/', variables('availabilitySetName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "availabilitySet": {
                    "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/availabilitySets', variables('availabilitySetName'))]"
                }, 
      ...},
```

The quckstart templates are a good ref: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/azure/azure-quickstart-templates/master/201-2-vms-2-FDs-no-resource-loops/azuredeploy.json

Once you have two or more VMs of the same size in an availability set, you would configure autoscale using microsoft.insights/autoscalesettings, which I beleive you referenced in the question. This is done at the cloud service so it will work similar to PaaS... like so:

```
{
      "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
      "name": "[concat(variables('vmName'), '-', resourceGroup().name)]",
      "type": "microsoft.insights/autoscalesettings",
      "location": "East US",
      ...},
```

A pretty good example is here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/6abc9f320e39d9d75dffb60846e88ab80d3ff33a/201-web-app-sql-database/azuredeploy.json

I also setup autoscale using the portal first and reviewed ARMExplorer to get a better idea of how things should look in my code. ARMExplorer is here: [Azure Resource Explorer](https://resources.azure.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I do have an availability set for my VMs. What I don't have is a cloud service, instead using a publicIP and loadbalancer, as per [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cloud_solution_architect/archive/2015/05/05/creating-azure-vms-with-arm-powershell-cmdlets.aspx) which suggests cloud services have been deprecated in ARM? Do you have a complete example of the autoscaling stanza when it applies to VMs? What would the targetResourceUri point to, etc? Thanks for the link to the Explorer, that's really useful to know about!

Comment: did you find an answer on the questions in the comment here?